# ActiveMQ, does multiple-consumers on a topic slow down the producer send rate?

Tags: activemq-classic

*some configurations here:
non-durable consumer,non-persistent message,disabled flow control,default prefetch size,optimizeAcknowledge = true,asynsend = true, use jms to connect ActiveMQ*

for example,

one producer、one consumer，

```
Producer————Topic————consumer
```

the producer send rate can reach 6k/s

but,in this case:
one producer  three consumer,

```
                /——consumer

Producer——-Topic——-consumer

                \——consumer
```

the producer send rate drop down to 4k/s

Here is my some of the key code:

sender class:

```
public class sender {

    public Boolean durable=false;
    public String clientID=null;
    public Boolean transacted=false;
    public int ackMode=Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE;
    public int timeToLive=0;
    public String queuename = "";
    public int persistent = DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT;

    public Connection createConnection(String user,String pwd,String url) throws JMSException, Exception {   
         ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(user, pwd, url);
         connectionFactory.setDispatchAsync(true);
         //connectionFactory.setAlwaysSessionAsync(false);
         Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();   
         if (durable && clientID!=null) {   
             connection.setClientID(clientID);   
         }   
         connection.start();   
         return connection;   
        }  

    public Session createSession(Connection connection) throws Exception {   
        Session session = connection.createSession(transacted, ackMode);   
        return session;   
       }   

    public MessageProducer createProducer(Session session) throws JMSException {   
        Queue destination = session.createQueue(queuename);   
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);   
        producer.setDeliveryMode(persistent);   

        if( timeToLive!=0 )   
            producer.setTimeToLive(timeToLive);   
        return producer;   
        }   

    public void onMessage(Message message) {   
         //process message   
         } 
}
```

sendmain method：

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sender s = new sender();
        s.persistent = DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT;
        Connection c = s.createConnection("","","tcp://localhost:61616?jms.useAsyncSend=true");
        Session sess = s.createSession(c);
        Topic topic = sess.createTopic("topic.test");
        MessageProducer mp = sess.createProducer(topic);
        StringBuffer tmpsb=new StringBuffer();
        for (int j=0;j<1024;j++)
        {
        tmpsb.append("0");
        }
        Message m = sess.createTextMessage(tmpsb.toString());
        long pre=System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        {
            mp.send(m);
        }
        long post=System.currentTimeMillis();
        mp.close();
        System.out.println("sendtime:"+(post-pre));
        System.out.println("sendrate:"+10000000/(float)(post-pre));
        System.out.println("timenow:"+(post));
    }
```

receiver class code:

```
public class receiver implements MessageListener
{
    public  int receivetimes=0;
    public long pretime;

    public void onMessage(Message msg)
    {
        //TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) msg;
        try {
            if (receivetimes==0)
            {
                pretime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            receivetimes+=1;
            if (receivetimes==10000)
            {
                long now=System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("time:"+(now-pretime)+"\nrecive rate:"+9999999/(float)(now-pretime));
                System.out.println("timenow:"+(now));
                receivetimes=0;
            }

        } catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*receiver class code here has hide some methods,such as createConnection,createSession or something just like sender class does.*

receiver main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        receiver s = new receiver();
        Connection c = s.createConnection("","","tcp://localhost:6151?jms.optimizeAcknowledge=true");
        Session sess = s.createSession(c);
        Topic destination  = sess.createTopic("topic.test");   
        MessageConsumer  consumer = sess.createConsumer(destination);  
        consumer.setMessageListener(new receiver());   
    }
```

Every consumer is in a standalone process. I ran three consumer and one producer then I got a result of bad performance. Does any one knows why I get this?

Comment: I hope asyncsend is enabled on the connection. There can be an impact if it is set to false. Usually, asyncsend is true for non-persistent messaging.

Comment: asyncsend has set 'true' already

Comment: can you tell me how you are measuring the rate of messages.

Comment: Are the consumers durable topic consumers?  A bit more configuration and use case information would help

Comment: @TimBish some configuration has given in first line,non durable consumer.Now I want to know does any one ever test ActiveMQ and can give some advises on it.

Comment: @user-soma Send the messages as fast as you can. You can get the amount of the messages and time then you can figure out the send rate.

Comment: @user2172171, thanks. i dint ask how i want to measure. i wanted to know how you measured so me or some one in this forum could find if the counting methodology had an issue.

Comment: Are producers / consumers / broker all on the same machine.  Still hard to say for certain what is happening as the analysis seems to high level yet to pinpoint a bottleneck.

Comment: @TimBish e....e   that's the key = =!

Answer (score 0):

Just as @TimBish said.
The issue is 'producer,consumer,activemq-server on same machine'.When separated,the issue never shows up.

It is so important to test something in a strict way.......